# shell command to create files

Tags: android, adb, fsutil

I want to create files with different sizes on an Android device.
The one approach I have already tried was to create dummy files using `fsutil` and push it to devices.

Is there any way to achieve similar result with a command inside `adb shell`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using `dd` command. I am not pretty sure it's available in your device. It works fine in my device, you can give a try.

In your host which connects with your Android device, with `adb` debug turn on, using the following command to create dummy file.

```
adb shell 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/local/tmp/test.img bs=4k count=800'
# check the result
adb shell ls -l /data/local/tmp/test.img
-rw------- shell    shell     3276800 2017-06-21 17:33 test.img
```

The command above will get data from `/dev/zero` and output to `/data/local/tmp/test.img` (a public writable directory for Android device), adjust `bs` and `count` value in your situation.

Comment: Thanks, @Alijandro, this solves some of my purposes.